# Why do I have a darker background-color than I set?

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/SynergyOfLife/pen/rPVYQW.

I have a sticky header with a dropdown menu. It *works* just fine, but around my dropdown menu, I have a darker background color than the rest of my header on my main `li` items.

```js
var $fixme   = $( '.fixme' );
var fixmeTop = $fixme.offset().top;
var $main    = $( 'main' );
var $win     = $( window );

$win.scroll( function () {

  var atSticky = $win.scrollTop() >= fixmeTop;
  
  $fixme.toggleClass( 'sticky', atSticky );
  $main.css( 'padding-top', atSticky ? fixmeTop + 5 : 0 );
  
} );

$(function () {
  $(document).scroll(function () {
    var $nav = $(".fixme");
    $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(css/bootstrap.min.css);
@import url(css/font-awesome.min.css);

/*  Min CSS  */

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.span-width {
  width: 100%;
}

.align-right {
  float: right;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #181818;
  color: #dddddd;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.fixme {
  width: 100%;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 34px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: 0 solid transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}

ul,
ol {
  margin: 0;
}

ul li,
ol li {
  list-style: none;
}


/* Header Area CSS */

.header-area {
  width: 100%;
}

.header-area .top-header-area {
  height: 85px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-area .top-header-area .top-search-area form {
  position: relative;
  width: 255px;
}

.header-area .top-header-area .top-search-area form input {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #ababab;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-area .top-header-area .top-search-area form button {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #555555;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 42px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
}

.header-area .top-header-area .top-search-area form button:hover {
  color: #20d8da;
}

.header-area .top-header-area .login-area a {
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #555555;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 42px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background-color color ease-in-out 400ms;
  width: 160px;
}

.header-area .top-header-area .login-area a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: #f06040;
}

.p {
  color: green;
  padding: 20px 0;
}


/*  NavBar CSS  */

.header-area .fixme #main-navigation {
  background-color: #181818e6;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 20px 110px 0 110px;
  width: auto;
}

.header-area .fixme #main-navigation li {
  background-color: #181818e6;
  position: relative;
}

.header-area .fixme #main-navigation>li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.header-area .fixme #main-navigation li a {
  color: #f06040;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: .5em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header-area .fixme #main-navigation li a:hover {
  color: #20d8da;
}

.header-area .fixme ul.folder-child {
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 150px;
}

.header-area .fixme #main-navigation li:hover>ul.folder-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.hidden-caret {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
    <header class="header-area">
  <div class="top-header-area">
    <p style="float: left; font-size: 32px;">Logo Here</p>
    <div class="row h-100 align-items-center right">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="d-flex">
          <div class="top-search-area">
            <form action="#" method="post">
              <input type="search" name="top-search" id="topSearch" placeholder="Search">
              <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="login-area">
            <a href="#"><span>Login / Register</span> <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fixme">
    <ul id="main-navigation">
      <li><a href="#">Fill <i class="fa fa-caret-down hidden-caret"></i></a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">In <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="folder-child">
          <li><a href="">a</a></li>
          <li><a href="">b</a></li>
          <li><a href="">c</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">This <i class="fa fa-caret-down hidden-caret"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Here! <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="folder-child">
          <li><a href="">d</a></li>
          <li><a href="">e</a></li>
          <li><a href="">f</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact <i class="fa fa-caret-down hidden-caret"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
<p class="p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl nunc. Massa enim nec dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus. Diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices.
  <br>
<p class="p">Nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus. Tristique et egestas quis ipsum. Gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac auctor. Nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies. Vulputate odio ut enim blandit. Blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam. Purus in mollis nunc sed id semper risus.</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p>Nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus. Tristique et egestas quis ipsum. Gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac auctor. Nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies. Vulputate odio ut enim blandit. Blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam. Purus in mollis nunc sed id semper risus.</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p>Nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus. Tristique et egestas quis ipsum. Gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac auctor. Nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies. Vulputate odio ut enim blandit. Blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam. Purus in mollis nunc sed id semper risus.</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
</body>
```

I have deleted all the `background-color` selectors, one by one, but I still get the weird background color.

I am using `rgba`, so the overlapping background colors may make it darker. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this rule:

```
.header-area .fixme #main-navigation { /* and/or ... li */
    background-color: #181818e6;
}
```

If you want to keep the explicit styling, remove the last two characters. They essentially change the gray and make the first two characters an alph-channel (transparency) modifier.

Comment: Are you familiar with your browser's document inspector? It's pretty easy to find offending styles these days.

Comment: Yes! My `#main-navigation li` had a "rougue" backgrounc-color tag. Thanks.